# Why is the group of units in a valued ring a topological group?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

Let $A$ be a ring and $v$ be a valuation on $A$ with value group $\Gamma$. The open sets are: $U=\{a \in A:v(a)< \gamma\}$ for $\gamma \in \Gamma$. 
How should I show that the group of units endowed with the subspace topology is a topological group?
(Indeed I want to show that the product and inverse are continuous...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The group of units has valuation 0. Valuation 0 elements correspond to an open set in your definition, in fact a minimal one. What should the subspace topology look like here? What should the preimage under multiplication and inverse of open sets look like in this topology?

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Why the group of units has valuation 0? I think this is not true because in a valued field, every non zero element is unit... But just 0 has the valuation 0...

Comment: 0 has the valuation $\infty$

Comment: @Aragogh there are different conventions for valuations going on here. I think for OP, $\Gamma$ is meant to be a multiplicative group, whereas you are thinking of it additively (of course, it's just notation).

Comment: Ah, I see the issue. Thank you for clearing that up!

Comment: The phrasing of the question also makes me confused about whether this is an arbitrary ring with some valuation on it or a valuation ring for a valuation on a field; otherwise the topology specified does not necessarily induce a the structure of a topological group, take for example the real numbers with the valuation $id: \mathbb{R}^{\times} \to \mathbb{R}^{\times} $, the inverse sends all elements less than 0 to elements greater than 0. If this is in specific a valuation ring, then what I said should just go through replacing 0 with 1.